# Changing the look of disabled Textbox so that I should not look that it is disabled in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How can I change the grayed background WPF TextBox so that it should not look like disabled TextBox? I'm actually using WPF's RichTextBox. Due to some reasons, I don't want to make it read-only but i want to disable it.

I want to do this through C# code not through XAML

Comment: I'm interested to hear the motivation for this. If it's disabled why not let it appear disabled? Why is read only not an option?

Comment: i have used hyperlinks inside that textbox if i m making textbox readonly hyperlinks and context menus are working. if i disable it it greyed, hence the approach that i used is make it readonly , disable its context menu and then disable its IsDocumentEnabled property. I am also not in favor of doing so but my senior wants that way only :(

Comment: this smells like bad design resulting in counter-intuitive UX ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without restyling the control is to override the `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey` brush in your resources. Something like this:

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary();
rd.Add(SystemColors.ControlBrushKey, Brushes.White);

var rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.Resources = rd;
```